# js scripts in index.html don't work after navigation to other page in ionic 3

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, materialize

I have added these scripts at the start of the body tag in index.html in ionic 3 app and these scripts will work on the first page but when I navigate to another page they won't work there any solution?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Including Custom CSS Files in the Ionic Build Process](https://www.joshmorony.com/including-custom-css-files-in-the-ionic-build-process/), and same process for jquery.

do not manipulate dom with jquery in angular apps

Comment: CSS is working fine, Js is not working after navigating

Comment: javascript needs to be bundled via ionic cli process

Comment: it's working fine on the first page but when I navigae to the next one it won't work there

Comment: can you mention exact step to include js through ionic cli?